# How to keep your data when model changes?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am learning entity framework. I am reading through some tutorials about initialization and how there are

- CreateDatabaseIfNotExists
- DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges
- DropCreateDatabaseAlways
- Custom DB Initializer

to choose from.

This makes me wonder, what does one do when they want to change the schema, but they want to keep the data they have?

I was just using sql directly, I could make temp tables, move stuff over, recreate the table with new columnns, move stuff back, etcv

What do you do when your classes and/or their relationships change in EF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your looking for EF migrations:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/

for every schema change you create a migration, where you can add or remove tables or columns, or you can even run your custom script.

Each migration has an Up method, these will be applied if you run your migration, and a Down method this is used if you want to roll back to the previous migration for some reason.

With `Update-Database` you can apply all migrations, and with `Update-Database –TargetMigration:{nameOfMigration}` you can migrate to a specific version.